# How Can I deal with Idleness in kafka source for watermarks using Table or SQL api?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We can handle the idleness in datastream api via this code block:

```
WatermarkStrategy
        .<Tuple2<Long,String>>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
        .withIdleness(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
```

But is something similar possible in flink table/SQL api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `table.exec.source.idle-timeout`. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/config/#table-exec-source-idle-timeout for more info.

Comment: Hi, would you know of any updates for this setting in Flink SQL between Flink 1.12 and Flink 1.13? I cannot get it working in Flink 1.12 but it works in 1.13. The release notes don't seem to have anything on this :(

Comment: David Anderson does the table.exec.source.idle.timeout closes the window and moves forward or does it let the other sources window proceed and mark the topic idle and keep increasing the window of that source but will not let bother the other sources? I want to understand more what this configuration does?